# symlinking in chef with version tag

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Can i create a symlink like this in chef ?

```
link "/usr/local/something-1.2-30" do
    to "/usr/local/something-new" 
    link_type :symbolic
    action :create
end
```

I tried the above but it failing.

Comment: What is `something-1.2-30` supposed to be? A file on a specific node?

Comment: yes, that's correct .it's a file and want to link

Comment: I do not understand then what you mean by a file with a version tag - is the name of the file `something`, but you want another version of the file (from a specific cookbook version)?

Comment: What isn't working?